# What is meant by 'probability of transition per unit time'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, terminology, differentiation

Today I came across a term used by Feynman in his [thirteenth lecture](http://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_13.html): '*probability per unit time*' to go from $| 1\rangle$ to $|2\rangle$ while initially being at $|1\rangle$. This is the excerpt from his lecture (emphasis mine):

> $$
> i\hbar\,\frac{d{C_n(t)}}{dt}=E_0C_n(t)-AC_{n+1}(t)-AC_{n-1}(t).$$ 
>   The first coefficient on the right, $E_0$, is, physically, the energy the electron would have if it couldn’t leak away from one of the atoms. [...] The next term represents **the amplitude per unit time** that the electron is leaking into the $n$th pit from the $(n+1)$st pit; and the last term is the amplitude for leakage from the $(n−1)$st pit. As usual, we’ll assume that $A$ is a constant (independent of $t$).

Then I googled a bit came before [Fermi's golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) which states:

> In quantum physics, Fermi's golden rule is a simple formula for the constant transition rate (**probability of transition per unit time**) from one energy eigenstate of a quantum system into other energy eigenstates in a continuum, effected by a perturbation.
>   $$
> \Gamma_{i\to k} = \frac{d}{dt} |a_k(t)|^2 = \frac{2|\langle k | H^\prime | i\rangle |^2}{\hbar^2}\frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}
> $$

So, the **probability of transition per unit time** is given by the derivative $$\frac{d}{dt}|a_k(t)|^2.$$ But isn't it the *change in probability of transition with respect to time* & not just *probability of transition per unit time*? After all, I learnt that derivatives represent how fast some quantity change *instantaneously* with respect to change in some other quantity(ies); applying it here, I couldn't find any reason why it shouldn't be called *change in probability of transition with respect to time*. I am not understanding why  *probability of transition per unit time* is related to the derivative as *derivative does represent the rate of change of some quantity & not the quantity*; isn't it ridiculous to call $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ **velocity per unit time**? I'm not understanding what **probability of transition per unit time** actually means. Can anyone please, please explain this to me?

Comment: The phrase you mention doesn't appear in Feynman's text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what might be confusing you. Assume, as in most cases with the Golden rule, that the transition rate is constant, $\Gamma$.  So, *for small times*, the 
cumulative transition probability is $W=\Gamma t$.

Think of the transition as leakage from a vessel. At $t=0$, no water has been lost, but with a constant rate of leakage, $\Gamma$, the longer the leakage lasts, the more water is lost to the vessel, so then the leakage rate, the transition rate, is $\frac{\mathrm{d}W}{\mathrm{d}t}=\Gamma$. The picture is the same if you gave $\Gamma$ a time dependence, when $W=\int\Gamma \, \mathrm{d}t$.

As for English usage, what does "elevation gain per unit of time" tell you when going up the mountain in a gondola?